# Can you set css image-rendering on an image cursor?

Tags: css

Heres an example: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki

The cursor is blurry, it would be nicer to set image-rendering: pixelated, crisp etc on it.

Can you do it?

[Here is a js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23kqwogs/)

```
.test {
    background: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
 cursor: url(https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/e/e1/WikiSwordCursor.png), auto;
}

img {
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
}
```

Comment: first you can read the image in java script canvas. then after enhancing the image you can set it back to cursor.

Answer (score -2):

```css
img {
  cursor: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/e/e1/WikiSwordCursor.png'),auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft/images/8/8a/AdvancementsTwitter.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/670?cb=20170609131906" alt="">
```

Comment: Are your two answers supposed to be parts of the same solution? If so, you should merge them into one by editing one and pasting the content of the other one into it.