# Is it possible to set image-rendering: pixelated on a cursor?

Tags: css

I have a custom cursor:

```css
body{    
    cursor: url('../img/my-cursor.png'), pointer;
}
```

The cursor is pixel art, but right now it looks blurry because the scaling is not nearest neighbour. Is it possible to render the image as pixelated, sort of like this?

```css
body{    
    cursor: url('../img/my-cursor.png'), pointer;
    /* DOES NOT WORK */
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

The closest answer to this question is here: [Can you set css image-rendering on an image cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779761/can-you-set-css-image-rendering-on-an-image-cursor) which does not have adequate answers.

Comment: Would an SVG image be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined property to set the rendering algorithm for the cursor property.

You should be able to use the [`image-set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set) function however, which will  provide a way for setting different size sources for different pixel density monitors, and thus avoid the problematic rescale altogether:

```js
// If, like me, you don't have multiple sized sources, you can always make a few yourself:
async function getScaledImage(url, scale=1) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (!resp.ok) { throw "network error"; }
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  const { width, height } = bmp;
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bmp.width, bmp.height);
  canvas.width = width * scale;
  canvas.height = height * scale;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0, width * scale, height * scale);
  bmp.close();
  const output = await canvas.convertToBlob();
  return `url(${URL.createObjectURL(output)}) ${scale}x`;
}
(async () => {
  const url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png";
  document.body.style.setProperty("cursor", `image-set(${await getScaledImage(url, 1)}, ${await getScaledImage(url, 2)}, ${await getScaledImage(url, 3)}) 0 0, pointer`)
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
body {
  cursor: image-set(url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png) 1x) 0 0, pointer;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

If you need to rescale dynamically your image, another option, **which works only in Firefox**, is to wrap your bitmap image inside an SVG one with the `image-rendering` property set to `optimizeSpeed`. But this, weirdly, works only in Firefox.

```js
async function getDataURL(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (!resp.ok) { throw "network error"; }
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  await new Promise((res) => {
    reader.onload = res;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
  return reader.result;
}
(async () => {
  const bmpUrl = await getDataURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png");
  const url = `data:image/svg+xml,<svg image-rendering="optimizeSpeed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96" height="96"><image href="${bmpUrl}" width="100%" height="100%"/></svg>`
  document.body.style.setProperty("cursor", `url('${url}') 0 0, pointer`)
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
body { height: 100vh }
```

So, we have to resort on an ugly hack where we'll draw each pixel as an SVG `<rect>`:

```js
const toHex = (val) => val.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
async function getAsSVG(url, scale=1) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (!resp.ok) { throw "network error"; }
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  const { width, height } = bmp;
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bmp.width, bmp.height);
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
  bmp.close();
  const { data } = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  const rects = [];
  for (let y=0; y<height; y++) {
    for (let x=0; x<width; x++) {
      const i = ((y * width) + x) * 4;
      const r = data[i+0];
      const g = data[i+1];
      const b = data[i+2];
      const a = data[i+3];
      rects.push(`<rect fill="rgba(${[r,g,b,a].join()})" x="${x}" y="${y}" width="1" height="1"/>`);
    }
  }
  return `<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="${width*scale}" height="${height*scale}"
    viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}">
    ${rects.join("\n\t")}
  </svg>`;
}
(async () => {
  const markup = await getAsSVG("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png", 3);
  const url = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(markup)}`
  document.body.style.setProperty("cursor", `url('${url}') 0 0, pointer`)
})().catch(console.error);
```

```css
body { height: 100vh }
```

But really, just use the `image-set()` if you can.